# Pybrain: 'SupervisedDataSet' object has no attribute '_convertToOneOfMany'

Tags: python-3.x, pybrain

I am trying to understand the pybrain documentation. There is a demo for classification.

```
from pybrain.datasets            import ClassificationDataSet
from pybrain.utilities           import percentError
from pybrain.tools.shortcuts     import buildNetwork
from pybrain.supervised.trainers import BackpropTrainer
from pybrain.structure.modules   import SoftmaxLayer

from pylab import ion, ioff, figure, draw, contourf, clf, show, 
hold, plot
from scipy import diag, arange, meshgrid, where
from numpy.random import multivariate_normal

means = [(-1,0),(2,4),(3,1)]
cov = [diag([1,1]), diag([0.5,1.2]), diag([1.5,0.7])]
alldata = ClassificationDataSet(2, 1, nb_classes=3)
for n in range(400):
    for klass in range(3):
        input = multivariate_normal(means[klass],cov[klass])
        alldata.addSample(input, [klass])


alldata._convertToOneOfMany()
tstdata, trndata = alldata.splitWithProportion( 0.25 )

trndata._convertToOneOfMany( )
tstdata._convertToOneOfMany( )

print("Number of training patterns: ", len(trndata))
print("Input and output dimensions: ", trndata.indim, trndata.outdim)
print("First sample (input, target, class):")
print(trndata['input'][0], trndata['target'][0], 
trndata['class'][0])

fnn = buildNetwork( trndata.indim, 5, trndata.outdim, 
outclass=SoftmaxLayer )

trainer = BackpropTrainer( fnn, dataset=trndata, momentum=0.1, 
verbose=True, weightdecay=0.01)
```

And the error message shows that trndata and tstdata has not attribute '_convertToOneOfMany'. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks.